# Can I / How Do I call a Javascript in an iframe by URL-parameters

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I have several sites (same content, but different languages) and have to use an iframe. On top of iframe you can choose the language.
Since the user is already on e.g. french page, I do not want the user to initially see wrong language in iframe and have to choose language again.

I have no access to the code of the iframe-site.

The links on iframe-top for changing languages look like this:
GERMAN
FRENCH
....

As far as I understand HTML and JS by clicking on the link I call a JS function "chooseLanguage" and send parameter "1" or "2", etc

So my goal would be to include the function-call and parameter in the link to the iframe, so that with no additional user-input the page is displayed in right language. 
See my fantasy-code below...

on mygermanpage.com i want to call:

```
<iframe src="http://sitewithiframe.com/form.html&javascript:chooseLanguage(1)"></iframe>
```

on myfrenchpage.com i want to call:

```
<iframe src="http://sitewithiframe.com/form.html&javascript:chooseLanguage(2)"></iframe>
```

Comment: It is not possible to call JavaScript by including it in your URL. In the past, you might have been able to invoke the JavaScript method after the page loads, but CSRF security improvements have made that nearly impossible, especially if you don't own the iframe-sites. If you did, you could have just included the language as a query string parameter (e.g. page.html?lang=french), and then have that page react to the presence of the parameter.

Comment: Is this scenario workable: User opens main page, language is determined from current url in main page or other stored variable, javascript sets iframe url to appropriate language site?

Comment: corrected the "code" above.
sorry @charlietfl , when you say "sets iframe url to appropriate language", that´s exactly my problem

Comment: Ok so you just need to know which site to load in frame correct? If so...how can language of main parent page be determined?

Comment: I assume @Cᴏʀʏ did understand my problem. "It is not possible to call JavaScript by including it in your URL". I got my answer... and have to search different possibilities or let it like it is.